# Entity is not api accessible error in batch of managed package?

Tags: apex

I'm facing this issue while running batch of managed package.
and batch is running by system admin.
also I search that there is no common custom field and object of managed package and org.

Comment: Can you share which kind of issues you are facing ?

Comment: When i run the batch of managed package at that time an error occur: "Entity is not org accessible "

Comment: There is something in the code conflicting with your org. Only the developer of the package can diagnose.

Comment: In my experience, this error typically occurs at compile time when saving code unless you're using dynamic apex, which is likely what's happening in the managed package. An object in a class very likely isn't being recognized as a legit object, sometimes because of a spelling error. Could also be an issue with namespacing. Suggest you contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

I think It may be duplicate of https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097pOIAQ

Or it may be a case of with sharing and without sharing, Please check permissions

Comment: This error occurred while running batch of managed packaged and in other org it is working as expected but only in a single org this type of error occur.